# Stop a flash video before it starts

Tags: flash, video

I'm comfortable with PHP and Javascript but this is the first time I'm using flash. I have Flash CS5.

I've managed to import a movie file, however, as soon as it's downloaded it starts playing. I've tried using the Action stop(); coding, which works file in the export preview in CS5, but on a website it runs straight away.

I know I can't use the  command because that stops the timeline but by then the video is already playing. My solution would be to use  and have the video in frame 2, then get javascript to jump to frame 2 when I was ready. However, I can't find a way to import a video file to a frame in CS5. Is there a better way?

Any help would be much appreciated.
Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are better off ignoring the frames and controlling the assets from a single frame via code. Can you post a sample of code to show how you are importing the video?

If you are using the FLVPlayback component then set *autoPlay* to *false*.

If you are using a Video Object then pause the NetStream until you are ready to play (*ns.pause();*) then to start use *ns.resume();*

Comment: I'm doing a file->import->import video and importing a url which is a f4v file. Not sure how to go from here

Comment: The next step is to choose a video skin and then the IDE automatically sets up the FLVPlayback component. Select Window>Component Inspector. With the component selectd on the stage you should see a list of parameters. Change autoPlay to false.

Comment: Hi Martin. The video still plays even with autoPlay unticked

Comment: Strange. Have you checked that the files are not cached in your browser?

Comment: Got it!! Thanks Martin!! Now the bizarre problem of how to get the video started via javascript. For some reason document.getElementById("clip1").Play(); doesn't run it.

Comment: That's another question... You need to look at setting up an External Interface method in the swf, that you can call using javascript. Here's a starter: http://lightness.co.uk/external-interface-examples/